# Regex to match PHP serialized data inside a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm working with Zend Framework 2's session manager in PHP, and want to unserialize the session data so I can change the way the data is stored. I thought regex was the way to do it, but I can't figure out how to make sure the regex is right for this type of string.

Sample input:

```
__ZF|a:2:{s:20:"_REQUEST_ACCESS_TIME";d:1099999999.9999999999999999999999;s:6:"_VALID";a:1:{s:25:"Zend\Session\Validator\Id";s:26:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";}}initialized|C:23:"Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject":403:{a:4:{s:7:"storage";a:3:{s:4:"init";i:1;s:10:"remoteAddr";s:13:"127.000.00.01";s:13:"httpUserAgent";s:114:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";}s:4:"flag";i:2;s:13:"iteratorClass";s:13:"ArrayIterator";s:19:"protectedProperties";a:4:{i:0;s:7:"storage";i:1;s:4:"flag";i:2;s:13:"iteratorClass";i:3;s:19:"protectedProperties";}}}
```

Expected output:

```
'__ZF|a:2:{s:20:"_REQUEST_ACCESS_TIME";d:1099999999.9999999999999999999999;s:6:"_VALID";a:1:{s:25:"Zend\Session\Validator\Id";s:26:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";}}'
'initialized|C:23:"Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject":403:{a:4:{s:7:"storage";a:3:{s:4:"init";i:1;s:10:"remoteAddr";s:13:"127.000.00.01";s:13:"httpUserAgent";s:114:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";}s:4:"flag";i:2;s:13:"iteratorClass";s:13:"ArrayIterator";s:19:"protectedProperties";a:4:{i:0;s:7:"storage";i:1;s:4:"flag";i:2;s:13:"iteratorClass";i:3;s:19:"protectedProperties";}}}'
```

What I tried:

```
$pattern = '/\w+\|.*?}}+/'; // this works for the sample input, but may be too general and certainly won't work for serialized data without a nested array
$pattern = '/\w+\|(a:\d+:{.*?}|o:\d+:\"[a-z0-9_]+\":\d+:{.*?})/'; // doesn't capture the `initialized` data
```

Where I am stuck:

Put generally, I can't figure out the best way to split apart the `__ZF` data from the `initialized` data (especially when there are other non-Zend variables in the session). Specifically, I can't figure out what regex to use to get serialized data.

I tried to put an example on RegexPlanet, but couldn't figure out the interface, and it only seemed to produce bizarre results. If it helps, I'm fairly sure <strike>ZF</strike> PHP produces its serialized session data like this:

```
$text = "";
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    $text .= $key . "|" . serialize($value);
}
```

...but I haven't found the source code for that.

Comment: Looks like you are working with JSON format when serialized. Instead of attack the problem with Regex, did you try to attact with JSON?!

Comment: @RodrigoGomes I didn't realize this was JSON. But I thought JSON was just a word for a particular formatting style. And in particular, the part of the data that I want to separate is not JSON, if I understand correctly. How can I use JSON here?

Comment: Your best bet may be [something involving `session_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php#113523).

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for replying. I tried that, but it kept returning false. But thanks to you I found out about ini_set('session.serialize_handler', 'php_serialize'); It changes the serialization to use PHP's regular serialize method instead of the alternate, which solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out about ini_set('session.serialize_handler', 'php_serialize'); It changes the serialization to use PHP's regular serialize method instead of the alternate, which solves the problem. – Miryafa